# passing json parameters to WCF function giving error "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details"

Tags: c#, jquery, json, wcf

i have a WCF service which takes in one string parameter. When i attempt to give call to it i get an error "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details"
I have reproduced this issue by passing json request from fiddler too.. just to be sure that my jQuery $.ajax() does not have the issue.

Here is my ServiceContract, WCF class and configuration -

Service Contract -

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface iAgentDesktop
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Transfer(string extensionNumber);
    [OperationContract]
    string Conference(string extensionNumber);
}
```

WCF Service

```
public class AgentDesktopMediator : iAgentDesktop
{
    string iAgentDesktop.Conference(string extensionNumber)
    {
            //do something
            return "";
    }
    string iAgentDesktop.Conference(string extensionNumber)
    {
        do something
        return "";
    }
}
```

configuration file -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFListener.AgentDesktopMediator">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8070/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="AgentDesktopMediator" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFListener.iAgentDesktop"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="jAgentDesktopMediator" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFListener.iAgentDesktop" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
```

Comment: if i do not pass a parameter, it does not throw any error.. just that my parameter is NULL then

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find actual error in the trace file. To create the trace file, first create a folder in your c drive called logs and put the following section in your wcf config file

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\logs\Traces.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Now whenever you call your service it will pull all the diagnostic information in the trace file which you can double click and open in MS Trace viewer.

Comment: ok.. now.. i've got a WCF and then i am hosting it in the console applicaiton.. will this be in console application or in the WCF's config??

Comment: It should be in wcf config.

Comment: Did you create the folder?. Also can you show your config file again

Comment: Anil Goel - yes.. i have created this folder

Answer (score 0):

OK, my question was by itself incomplete.. i conclude this after the issue is resolved now..

the issue was that in my content type i did not put a semi-colon between contentType and charset..

this is what i provided in my $.ajax() -

```
Content-Type: application/json charset=utf-8
```

it had to be -

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

And, i never bothered to see the header while attempting to hit the service from fiddler too.. i was concentrating only on the format of data that i was supplying